# Mocking flickr api for better unit testing

Tags: java, json, rest, flickr

I am creating an application,that uses Flickr's API.I wanted to know if it's possible to mock Flickr's API so that I can run my test offline.I am developing the application the application in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write an adapter for flickr API access only for a loose coupling and a better testability.